# what does the background color mean?

Tags: discussion, design

I am reading questions at [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/). I realize that some of the questions are in the yellow background color, while the rest are in pure white backgronud.

May I know what does the background color mean?

Many thanks. :)

Comment: Congrats, you have favorite tags. :)